# Snowpark - union_all returns null value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running this code in Snowflake on a Python worksheet:

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 

    df1 = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], schema=["a", "b"])
    df2 = session.create_dataframe([[0, 1], [3, 4]], schema=["c", "d"])
    df3 = df1.union_all(df2).show()

    return df3
```

I'm expecting it to return the union of the 2 dataframes as a new dataframe but it returns a null value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A little explanation for what you are seeing: method chaining in Python is very handy but the results aren't always what you would expect. In this instance, DataFrame.show() function returns None, so you get a null value as a result of the entire chain.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame.show

Answer (score 0):

```
import snowflake.snowpark as snowpark

def main(session: snowpark.Session): 

    df1 = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], schema=["a", "b"])
    df2 = session.create_dataframe([[0, 1], [3, 4]], schema=["c", "d"])
    df3 = df1.union_all(df2)
    df3.show()
    
    return df3
```

Comment: Is this the same code as in the question?

Comment: No the last 2 lines before return different, this answer does the union first and displays the data frame

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: (@demircioglu has effectively done you for you—you might point out something similar in your answer itself for clarity.)

Answer (score 0):

As Dave comment says: You shouldn't return the result of `df3.show()`, but `df3` instead:

```py
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    df1 = session.create_dataframe([[1, 2], [3, 4]], schema=["a", "b"])
    df2 = session.create_dataframe([[0, 1], [3, 4]], schema=["c", "d"])
    df3 = df1.union_all(df2)

    # Print a sample of the dataframe to standard output.
    df3.sh[![enter image description here][1]][1]ow()

    # Return value will appear in the Results tab.
    return df3
```

[image]